# Ошибка Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("*","*","*","*");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("ERROR %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
    }
    $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM rows");
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->get_result()->fetchAll();
    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();
```

Результат данного кода - Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: может все-таки bind_result(), а не get_result() ?..

Comment: Ну, мне нужно получить результаты, а потом зафетчить их в массив. Думаю всё-таки get.
Но я попробовал ваш вариант и при таком раскладе он выдаёт "Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object"

Comment: вас не смутил си-стиль с кэмелКейзом в одной строке?

    $rows = $result->get_result()->fetch_all();

Comment: Поправил, но увы, всё осталось на своих местах...

Comment: @Andy1295 хм, а какая версия PHP? Установлен ли mysqlnd?

Comment: 5.5.18. mysqlnd установлен.

Comment: @Andy1295, странно, этот метод должен идти вместе с ним, и в интернете у этой ошибки только эта причина. Там нет какого-нибудь суффикса `-pdo`?

Comment: @Etki Нет, PDO нет.
Увы, в интернете тоже не нашёл ничего, вот сюда и написал...

Answer (score 1):

Про опечатку в комментариях разобрались - надо `fetch_all()`, а не `fetchAll()`.

А вот про `mysqlnd` субъективные ощущения автора вступают в противоречие с объективной реальностью, данной нам в ощущениях. <s>Нет ножек - нет и варенья</s> Если нет функции `get_result()`, то `mysqli` 100% скомпилирована без `mysqlnd`.

Поэтому варианта мы имеем три:

1. Поставить таки `mysqlnd`
2. Работать с mysqli без `get_result()`. **САМЫЙ** адовый вариант, врагу не пожелаешь - mysqli prepared statements из коробки - это ужасно. Но в принципе в сети полно велосипедов, которые с большим или меньшим успехом прикручивают к `mysqli` привычный функционал `fetch_array()`.
3. Воспользоваться какой-нибудь библиотекой-надстройкой над mysqli. Например [safemysql](http://www.phpfaq.ru/safemysql). Это решит все проблемы.

   ```
   $rows = $db->getAll("SELECT id,name FROM rows");
   ```

*одной строчкой.*